# How do I print data in a csv file that corresponds to another column?

Tags: python, pandas, file, csv

I am attempting to print the every value under the attribute `Title` of a csv file that corresponds to the the value (`'Image segmentation'`) under the attribute `Field`. I've tried numerous codes to figure this out but keep getting the wrong answer or no answer at all. My latest attempt is below. I'm not sure where to go from here so any help is appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd

data_file=pd.read_csv('7papers.csv')
data_file.columns=data_file.columns.str.strip()

field=data_file.Field

title=data_file.Title

for field in data_file:
    if field == ('Image segmentation'):
        print(title)
```

Comment: can you share the csv file

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain I'm following your question and as commented above seeing the csv file would help, but it sounds like you are wanting to do this:

```
print data_file.loc[ data_file.Field == 'Image segmentation', 'Title' ]
```

This says "select the rows where `Field` has the value we want and then print the value of `Title` in those rows". Does that work?

Comment: yes, this worked. I apologize for the awkward wording. Thank you for the help.